# How do I pass in feed credentials to XDocument that allows Linq to XML to work

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-xml

I can take the results of my variable xmlDoc and save it to an xml document (on disk) and the query returns results; however, when I run it live (with the code below) the query results are null.

Why is my query not working against the xmlDoc?? See screen shot below for the debug output 'xmlDoc.Root'.

There must be a cleaner way to create the XDocument??

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("bagee18@gmail.com", "my_password");

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(wc.DownloadString(new Uri("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom")), LoadOptions.None);



var q = (from c in xmlDoc.Descendants("entry")

        select new
        {
            name = c.Element("title").Value,
            url = c.Element("link").Attribute("href").Value,
            email = c.Element("author").Element("email").Value
        }).ToList();

q.Dump();
```

xmlDoc.Root:

[image: screen shot of XML].

Answer (score 0):

Take the namespace into account:

```
XNamespace df = xmlDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;

var q = (from c in xmlDoc.Descendants(df + "entry")

        select new
        {
            name = c.Element(df + "title").Value,
            url = c.Element(df + "link").Attribute("href").Value,
            email = c.Element(df + "author").Element(df + "email").Value
        }).ToList();
```